Possible to notch out a joist cross support?
The enclosed pictures from my attic show two sides of a cross support that runs perpendicular across the top of the ceiling joists of a 12' x 12' bedroom.  This bedroom is in the corner of a single-story house.  The ceiling joists are 2x6.  The upright support board is a 2x6, while the flat-laying board is a 2x4.  There are two ceiling joists pictured running below the cross support.  Nothing else appears to be supported by the cross support.  I assume this support is here to keep the ceiling joists from sagging?  There is a ceiling fan in the middle of the room.  The first joist (towards the bottom left of the picture) is about 20" from an interior wall.
The problem is that the cavity between the two pictured joists is a very ideal place (nearly the only accessible place in the room) to install a MRCOOL mini-split ceiling cassette. To get vertical clearance for the ceiling cassette, the 2x4 of the cross support would need to be removed between the two ceiling joists, and the about 3" of the 2x6 would need to be notched out between the two ceiling joists.  Is it possible to remove these items from the cross support and somehow adequately reinforce the remaining portion of the 2x6 cross support with steel/aluminum angle or unistrut channel lagged to the top of the 2x6?
We can shove the ceiling cassette completely to the left of the cross support, but that would put the refrigerant connection end of the cassette really close to the exterior wall, and given the roof slope it will very challenging to get in there to make the refrigerant connections.
Thanks!



Got pics with more context?

Unfortunately, there is not much else than can be seen because of insulation.  It's just basically a 12'x12' room with 2x6 ceiling joists on a 16" spacing, and this support runs across the top of the joists, pretty much centered in the room.   The support boards are nailed into the ceiling joists.  I had a good look at the support when the attic was reinsulated, and that's pretty much it.  There is one other room in the house, with a flat ceiling that has a similar support.  The other rooms have vaulted ceilings and a more complex structure.
